# How to apply different FOR loops for different columns of a dataframe based on the class type of that column in R Language?

Tags: r, dataframe

for example, if the column class is numeric then apply math functions, for example mean(). If the next column is date then min date, max date etc..

```
S.NO NAME MARKS DOB
1.    X     90  1-2-1991
2.    Y     80  1-3-1991
3.    Z     70  1-4-1991
```

consider this as a sample dataset. How to apply different functions for the columns in the dataset? the function should be selected depending on the class of the column.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a function that checks for the variable class and returns a different value, and then use lapply on the data.frame. Here is an example with arbitrary functions.

```
lapply(d,function(x) {
  if(class(x) %in% c("numeric","integer")) mean(x)
  else if(class(x) == "Date") min(x)
  else if(class(x) == "character") nchar(x)
})
```

data

```
txt <- readLines(n=4)
S.NO NAME MARKS DOB
1.    X     90  1-2-1991
2.    Y     80  1-3-1991
3.    Z     70  1-4-1991
d <- read.table(text=txt,head=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
d$DOB <- as.Date(d$DOB)
```